# Could I request support in amending a class innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Apologies if my experience is limited. I have the below

```
<a class="this=is">Touch here</a>
```

and I'm trying to use Tampermonkey to change the Tap Here to instead say Don't touch. I've tried the below but to no success:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Button repair
// @namespace    ****
// @version      0.1
// @description  Edit the text on the button
// @author       N/A
// @match        https://website*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var el =
    document.querySelectorAll("this-is");
el.innerHTML = "Don't touch"
```

Could anyone help me understand this? I would greatly appreciate your support

Comment: The class you used is `this=is`, not `this-is`, Also, `querySelectorAll` returns a list of elements. You should use `querySelector` instead

Comment: My apologies, the HTML was incorrectly written - it should have said this-is above. I'll also try to change to querySelector and see if this helps. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you're targeting a class with querySelector it should be `const el = document.querySelector('.this-is')` - note the `.` in the selector which tells you its a class. [Here's the full documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).